# not creating and writing excel in xlxswriter package in scrapy

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I am writing a code to crawl site with python selenium the code execute and print the details what I want but I want to store it in excel file using xlxswriter in python. Here is my code

```
import xlsxwriter
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
row = 0
col = 0
r=1
if r:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('fit1.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i in range(1,3):
    url = 'http://www.examble.com/kids//page-%d.html' % i
    for j in range(1,36):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        delay = 2 # seconds
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'religionToJs')))
            print "Page is ready!"
        except TimeoutException:
            print "Loading took too much time!"
        xpath = "//*[@id='wrapper']/main/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]/a" % j
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        elem.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')
        gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td')
        meaning = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td')
        religion = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td')
        orgin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td')
        variants = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-name-info"]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td')
        #workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('fit.xlsx')
        #worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write(row, col,name.text)
        worksheet.write(row, col+1,gender.text)
        worksheet.write(row, col+2,meaning.text)
        worksheet.write(row, col+3,religion.text)
        worksheet.write(row, col+4,orgin.text)
        worksheet.write(row, col+5,variants.text)
        row = row + 1
        if name.text:
            print name.text
            print row
        else:
            print "dfdfg"
        driver.close()
        #workbook.close()
#workbook.close()
```

In this code after some condition the excel is created. So I added the creating excel code in the inner for loop in that for loop it always open and writing data correctly but it deletes previous data it's not appending the data to a new row what is the solution for that

Comment: everytime you start program you set `row=0` so you overwrite previous values. At start you have to get how many rows are already used and set `row` correctly.

Comment: thanks for replying if I run the code row is working correctly only the problem is data is not appending to the excel file. Row is increasing correctly because the last data(100) is stored in the 100th row. But the previous data is not there in the file.

Comment: XlsxWriter [cannot append to an existing file](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html). Try [OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) instead.

Comment: thank you. Here I am going to use openpyxl